# Fixed position images on responsive image

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I have a responsive image of a map. On top of that map I want to add some pins. These pins cannot change position when the screen size is changed. I've tried many things but the pins keep changing position when the screen size is changed. Does somebody know how I can fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF2ga.png)

[Screenshot large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbR39.png)

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute">
            <img src="worldmap.png" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 100px; width: 100%; height: auto">
            <img src="pin.png" style="max-width: 5%; top: 50px; left: 100px">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try setting a fixed width and height on the parent div instead of 100%

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I want to keep the image (worldmap) responsive

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Your comment is removed. I tried your code, but here you can see that the coordinates change when I view on desktop and on mobile: https://imgur.com/a/dDGNwh6

Comment: That's why I removed it. This is a good question, seems like there should be an easy answer but I can't figure it out either

Comment: I don't think this can be done without specific latitude/longitude coordinates. Might be worth checking out plotly.js: https://plotly.com/javascript/scattermapbox/

Comment: Scratch that I've figured it out, see my answer @Tom

Answer (score 1):

Try using `transform: translate(%, %)` and have them share the same parent `div`:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

img:nth-of-type(1) {
  max-width: 5%;
  transform: translate(400%, 100%);
  position: absolute;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative">
    <div id="map">
      <img src="http://www.apexdancestudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/map-pin-png-6.png" />
      <img src="https://cyberconceptslk.com/demo/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/World-Map-PNG-Photos.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This way the pin will reposition according to the parent, the same as the map is resized.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you very much @Daniel_Knights

Comment: Got there in the end!

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to explain the problem-

1. Here you have a image which is responsive because it is in `%` dimesions.
2. You have a pin which is absolutely placed over the image.
3. (main problem) the pin will change its place when compared to the map because it is positioned with a fixed value with left and top and these values never changes on size change or percentage change which happens with the map image as it changes size on screen size's change.
4. (The answer) Just define the `left` and `top` values for that pin image in terms of percentage `%` and then the pin will change position according to screen size but will remain to be at a same place as compared to other elements.

Kindly let me know wheresoever you face a problem and feel free to ask for an even deep explanation.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute">
        <img src="worldmap.png" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 10%; left: 25%; width: 100%; height: auto">
        <img src="pin.png" style="max-width: 5%; top: 50px; left: 100px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the problem now. However the pin still changes coordinates when I rescale my window. (if I scale diagonally this works perfect. But when I adjust just the screen width/height, the coordinates are not at the same place on the map anymore).

Comment: It happens because width and heights are different on different devices, their ratios are also different, and that's why we all make things responsive considering only 1 dimension and that is width so put all your values in terms of width by vw and then the coordinates will work fine on every device even when adjusted with width/height